# mutate `currentState` property in flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

I have a flutter app in which I display list of employees with by their name and salery in listView widget. I have two buttons for each employee to increase or decrease their salery.

I am using [flutter_bloc](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/) for state management.

Here is the Employee class.

```dart
class Employee extends Equatable {
  int _id;
  String _name;
  double _salery;

  Employee(this._id, this._name, this._salery);

  // setters
  set id(int id) {
    this._id = id;
  }

  set name(String name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  set salery(double salery) {
    this._salery = salery;
  }

  // getters
  int get id => this._id;
  String get name => this._name;
  double get salery => this._salery;
}
```

Here is the class as event.

```dart
@immutable
abstract class EmployeeEvent {
  final int _index;
  EmployeeEvent(this._index);

  int get index => this._index;
}

class IncrementEvent extends EmployeeEvent {
  IncrementEvent(int index) : super(index);
}

class DecrementEvent extends EmployeeEvent {
  DecrementEvent(int index) : super(index);
}
```

Here is the bloc class which handles the state.

```dart
class EmployeeBloc extends Bloc<EmployeeEvent, List<Employee>> {
  @override
  List<Employee> get initialState => [
        Employee(1, 'Employee One', 10000.0),
        Employee(2, 'Employee Two', 10000.0),
        Employee(3, 'Employee Three', 10000.0),
        Employee(4, 'Employee Four', 10000.0),
        Employee(5, 'Employee Five', 10000.0),
      ];

  @override
  Stream<List<Employee>> mapEventToState(EmployeeEvent event) async* {
    // I have checked, the control reaches over here.
    double currentSalery = currentState[event.index].salery;
    if (event is IncrementEvent) {
      // Increments the salery when user presses the increment button
      currentState[event.index].salery = currentSalery + (currentSalery * 0.2);
    } else if (event is DecrementEvent) {
      currentState[event.index].salery = currentSalery - (currentSalery * 0.2);
    }
    print(currentState[event.index].salery); // even prints the incremented / decremented salery.
    yield currentState;
  }
}
```

After yielding, the `BlocBuilder` from the widget class isn't called.

If I change the method like this then it calls `BlocBuilder` but I cann't increment or decrement the salery of employee at particular index.

```dart
@override
Stream<List<Employee>> mapEventToState(EmployeeEvent event) async* {
  if (event is IncrementEvent) {
    yield currentState;
  } else if (event is DecrementEvent) {
    yield currentState;
  }
}
```

How do I increment or decrement the salery of particular employee at particular index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [flutter bloc](https://felangel.github.io/) requires you to yield a new instance of the state, instead of modifying the currentState.

So I made the following changes in the below classes.

```dart
class Employee extends Equatable {
  int id;
  String name;
  double salery;

  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.salery) : super([id, name, salery]);

  Employee copyWith({
    String name,
    double salery,
  }) {
    return Employee(this.id, name ?? this.name, salery ?? this.salery);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Employee { id: $id, name: $name, salery: $salery }';
  }
}
```

Modified the mapEventToState method and added one helper method to update the list propertites.

```dart
@override
  Stream<List<Employee>> mapEventToState(EmployeeEvent event) async* {
    yield this.updateList(event);
  }

  Stream<EmployeeState> updateList(EmployeeEvent event) async* {
    final id = (currentState as EmployeeLoaded).employee[event.index].id;

    List<Employee> employeeUpdate =
        (currentState as EmployeeLoaded).employee.map((employee) {
      if (employee.id == id) {
        return employee.copyWith(
            salery: (event is IncrementEvent)
                ? employee.salery + 200
                : employee.salery - 200);
      }
      return employee;
    }).toList();

    print((currentState as EmployeeLoaded).employee == employeeUpdate);
    print(currentState == EmployeeLoaded(employeeUpdate));

    yield EmployeeLoaded(employeeUpdate);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem is that you don't have any class that represent your state. So first you should create needed states. You can use simple examples provided in the `bloc` [website](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/).

And for the global understanding :

The `BlocBuilder` will rebuild only on these case (With `equatable`):

- The instance runtime type of the new and the old state are different
- The instance of the new and the old state are the same instance type it will deeply compare all nested properties of the previous and the new state to know what have changed by calling `==`.
- You can also use `conditional` property function that you provide on creation.

If you want to use the same instance you can extends `Equatable` (from `equatable` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable)) or do the same thing it's doing. ([this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-equatable-package-simplify-equality-comparisons-1a96a3fc4864) medium post can help you).

With your case you can do this :

```dart
abstract class EmployeeState extends Equatable {
  EmployeeState([List props = const []]) : super(props);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType{}';
}

class EmployeeLoaded extends EmployeeState{
  EmployeeLoaded(this.employees):super([employees])

  final List<Employee> employees;
}
```

For further info/help you can come on the `bloc` [gitter](https://gitter.im/bloc_package/Lobby).